# Android CouchDB {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}

Tags: android, json, request, couchdb, iriscouch

While trying to Create a new Document in my IrisCouch Database, i am always getting following error: 
    {"error":"bad_request","reason":"invalid_json"}

This is the relevant part of my function:

```
try {
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://username.iriscouch.com:6984/mydb");
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(body);

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
    httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    System.out.println(httpResponse.toString()) ;
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

    // Get the response
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(httpEntity.getContent()));

    String line = "";
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    System.out.println("body: " + body);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is my System.out of "body":

```
{"bild1":"","bild2":"","bild3":"","bild4":"","bild5":"","bild6":"","bild7":"","bild8":"","bild9":"","bild10":"","name":"","plz":0,"ort":"","strasse":"","n_koordinate":0,"e_koordinate":0,"beschreibung":"","groesse":"< 50m²","sitzplaetze":"< 50","grillstellen":"1","reservierung":false,"res_name":"","res_tele":"","res_weiteres":"","wc":true,"behindi":false,"dach":true,"kinderfreundl":false,"auto":false,"kinderwagen":false,"einkauf":false,"datum":"2015-07-01-14:12:01:856","bewertung":0,"anz_bewertung":0}
```

The JSON is valid. Tested it with jsonlint.com JSON Validator.

What could i do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the unicode superscript 2 (²) is bothering it? 
Not sure which library this HttpPost is, but seems a lot like the HttpWebRequest, so try setting your header this way:

```
httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json charset=utf-8");
```

It could also be that the HttpPost class doesn't properly encode strings.
(I haven't pasted this in my Visual studio, so just a shot in the dark)

Comment: Thank you! This was the solution!